# How can I remove that line on a kind of spheric form?

Tags: texturing

I wanted to make a grape and the result is not bad but I have that line which kills everything. Does anyone know why it appears like that?
[image]

I used mix RGB with the option Color Dodge

Comment: Did you use a mirror modifier?

Comment: No, I used subdivision and displace

Comment: Are you using UV's to map the procedural textures?

Comment: maybe a normal problem? maybe show your whole node setup or share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/92155cb2cef14596849d4e96ede7bfa1

Comment: I am pretty new in Blender so for me it's still relatively complicated to understand fully

Comment: Try using the generated or object coordinates and lower the scale of your noise textures. The seam is caused by your UV seam. Alternatively you could design your shader so that it is seamless (more complicated)

Comment: I used generated and it worked !!! Thank you so much :)